# Postgres SQL UPDATE based on result of a previous SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

In Postgres 10 I want to perform an UPDATE twice. First UPDATE should run no matter what, updating the `alwaysupdate` column. And the second UPDATE should run only if the SELECT statement below returns a row count of 0, which means `sometimesupdate` should get updated only if all of the rows in `mytable` where `mykey = 100` have `sometimesupdate` set to `null`.

```
-- Run no matter what, updating 'alwaysupdate'
update mytable set alwaysupdate = now() where keyA = 100 and keyB = 200

-- Check the number of rows where 'sometimesupdate' has a value
select count(*) from mytable where keyB = 200 and sometimesupdate is not null

-- If 'sometimesupdate' is null for all rows above, give it a value in this row
update mytable set sometimesupdate = now() where keyA = 100 and keyB = 200
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? Is it possible to combine it into a single SQL statement? Otherwise multiple statements wrapped in a transaction? Otherwise a function if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method puts the logic in the `from` clause:

```
update mytable
    set alwaysupdate = now(),
        sometimesupdate = (case when b.cnt = 0 then now() else sometimesupdate end)
    from (select count(*) from mytable where keyB = 200 and sometimesupdate is not null
         ) b
    where keyA = 100 and keyB = 200;
```

However, `not exists` would usually have better performance:

```
update mytable
    set alwaysupdate = now(),
        sometimesupdate = (case when not exists (select 1 from mytable where keyB = 200 and sometimesupdate is not null)
                                then now()
                           end)
         ) b
    where keyA = 100 and keyB = 200;
```

Comment: In your second example doesn't `case` need an `else` like in the first example or would it work without? When you set `sometimesupdate = sometimesupdate`, does Postgres know not to update the table since nothing is actually changing, or do modification triggers etc still run in that case?

Comment: @user779159 . . . No.  The value will be set to `NULL` without the `else` -- but because of the logic of the query, we know the value is already `NULL`.  I will grant that the query might be clearer with an `ELSE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

if count is equal to zero then update to now() otherwise retain the old value of sometimesupdate

```
update mytable as A
 set alwaysupdate = now(),
 sometimesupdate = (case when (
       select count(*) from mytable as B where B.keyB = A.keyB 
       and sometimesupdate is not null) = 0 
    then now() 
  else sometimesupdate end)
where keyA = 100 and keyB = 200
```

or if you want to update that specific row which has no sometimesupdate and is keyb = 200 then do below

```
UPDATE mytable
SET alwaysupdate = now(),
    sometimesupdate = (CASE
      WHEN keyB = 200 THEN CASE
          WHEN sometimesupdate IS NULL THEN now()
          ELSE sometimesupdate
        END
      ELSE sometimesupdate
    END)
WHERE keyA = 100
AND keyB = 200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a chained CTE, and make the second update conditional on an `EXISTS(...)` [NOT EXISTS() is the same as COUNT()==zero]

---

```
  -- Run no matter what, updating 'alwaysupdate'
WITH u1 AS ( 
        UPDATE mytable 
        SET alwaysupdate = now() 
        WHERE keyA = 100 AND keyB = 200;
        RETURNING *
        )
UPDATE mytable u2
SET sometimesupdate = now() 
FROM u1
WHERE u1.keyA = u2.keyA -- 100
  AND u1.keyB = u2.keyB -- 200
        -- If 'sometimesupdate' is null for all rows below, give it a value in this row
        -- Check if there are any rows where 'sometimesupdate' has a value
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
        FROM mytable nx
        WHERE nx.keyB = u2.keyB -- 200
        AND sometimesupdate IS NOT NULL
        );
```